# CouchDB Conflict Errors

Tags: python, couchdb

Im pretty new to CouchDB and when trying to update a document Im getting conflict errors.

```
>>> cachefile_db["ABC"] = {1:1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 344, in __setitem__
    status, headers, data = resource.put_json(body=content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 531, in put_json
    **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 546, in _request_json
    headers=headers, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 542, in _request
    credentials=self.credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 394, in request
    raise ResourceConflict(error)
couchdb.http.ResourceConflict: (u'conflict', u'Document update conflict.')
```

I could prob delete the record and then readd it, what is the suggested/best way to avoid conflict errors ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The conflict appears because you do not have _rev in your document. I'd suggest to load the document from the db first (with _rev), than modify it and save back.